# Let $G=\Bbb Z$ and $H =m\Bbb Z$. What is $(G : H)$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\Bbb Z$ and $H =m\Bbb Z$. What is $(G : H)$? 
I think the answer is $m$, where $m$ is a positive integer. Because $-m\Bbb Z$ and $m\Bbb Z$ are identical. Help me

Comment: Without more info about $m$, one can only say that the index is $\infty$ for $m=0$ and is $|m|$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb Z/m \mathbb Z$ is an $m$-element group (the integers mod m) denoted $\mathbb Z_m$...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$(G:H)= \bigl|\mkern1mu G/H\mkern 1mu\bigr|.$$

Comment: Is this the order of quotient group G/H???

Comment: @ShampaDas yes. How many elements are in $G/H$?